# firebase don't show data in my web compte

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I work with firebase in android project. I just realised that the database work. But when I see my firebase account I don't see any data.
This is my problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");


    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);

    YoYo.with(Techniques.RotateInDownLeft)
            .duration(3000)
            .playOn(findViewById(R.id.appLogo));


}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("nizarab","nizar "+dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}}
```

in my log cat show "Hello, World!" but when i see my web compte i don't see the string data
[image: my compte]

Comment: I'm not sure why you have `getReference("condition")`

Comment: i was thinking to name it condition but when i delete it, getReference()
still doesn't work

Comment: Does the Firebase database have a condition reference?

Comment: no i just want to make the firebase work then i will add my references

Comment: Can you try `myRef.child("example").setValue("Hello, World!")`?

Comment: i tried and still show null in the compte

Comment: There's a good chance you don't have permission to write the data. See this page on how to detect that: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/19721/detect-errors-when-writing-a-value-on-android#t=201611200248016865392

Comment: i thing that the data was read and write beacause in my logcat show me the same data. i think that my problem like the data Stored in other database but really don't know where

Comment: i try to detect read permission and i don't see any errors